# How to obtain NFDUMP output in bytes using csv output

Tags: linux, netflow

I need to obtain netflow record in csv format, but as a lot of traffic is in network, nfdump return information in MBytes. I have no choise but to use one option in NFDUMP to obtain traffic information in bytes.

My current command is:

```
nfdump -R netflow/ -q -o csv 'src net 33.1.1.0/24 and dst net 33.1.2.0/24'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your are reading from a file:

```
nfdump -r nfcapd.2017xxxxx -o extended -o csv
```

will give headers and a summary, while:

```
nfdump -r nfcapd.2017xxxxx -o extended -o csv -q
```

removes both.

Not quite sure how to keep only the headers.